# Flex/AIR SQLite: Multiple Inserts, Unknown Number of Rows in 1 SQL Statement

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air, flash-builder

I am creating a Mobile APP in Flex/Adobe AIR. I am using SQLite to store and retrieve data. I have a situation where I need to INSERT an unknown number of rows into a table. Is there a way to do this with a single statement in SQLite? I know that it can be done using a loop in AS3, but wanted to see if it's possible with a single SQL statement.  I have found references to using UNIONS and SELECT, however, the examples weren't completely clear nor was I sure that they were applicable to my situation. Any examples are certainly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable 
VALUES
('Column 1 Row 1', 'Column 2 Row 1'),
('Column 1 Row 2', 'Column 2 Row 2'),
('Column 1 Row 3', 'Column 2 Row 3');
```

You'll still need to loop in AS to build the SQL statement, though.

Note that there seems to be [some confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) as to whether this syntax is supported by SQLLite.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it seems that the SQL syntax in your response will not work in SQLite. However, the link you referenced seems to resolve the issue.